# How to display alert or alerting user that username already exists

Tags: java, servlets

So i created a register jsp page and register form redirects to register servlet, servlet checks whether username exists if exists it redirects users back to register page, and if it doesn't then the data will be inserted into database,

Updated: everything works thanks

Comment: `FizzLinkUsers` class is needed here.

Comment: What is `out` - it's not defined in your example?

Comment: done fizzlink class should be with main post an dnope i don't use ajax everything you see up there besides fizzlink class at the end is servlet and printwriter is out,  yeah alert can be jscript but if you now any alternative it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should put this into a request parameter and pass (forward / include - you should try which fits best) it to the JSP page.

It would be something like this:

```
if (user.equals(unm)){
    request.setAttribute("error", "User Name Already Exists.");
    request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath() + "/FizzLinkRegister.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

On the JSP page, you then check if the attribute "error" is set and render the JavaScript part.

Answer (score 0):

This line, `flu.insert(unm, upas , uem, ufn, uln, udob , usx);` is passing parameters to the function `insert()`.

Here :

`String insertSQL  = "Insert into FizzUser VALUES ('" + getuName()+ "', '" + getuPass()+ "', '" + getuEmail()+ "', '" + getuFName()+ "', '" + getuLName()+ "', '" + getuDOB()+ "', '" + getuSex() + "')";`

you are using `getters()` to insert the values. The values have not been set to the variables in the class through `setters()` if there isn't an existing record. Use the parameters to the function to insert into the table.

Comment: problem is not with my fizzlink class read the last part of my orginal post i updated it

Comment: it was already inserting into db when i wasn't checking for username exists but when i used code to check for username like    if(username.equals(unm)) it worked and redirected user to register if username existed but didn't display alertbox